# How to get a display of camera without UI elements?

Tags: ios, swift, camera, photo

How to remove all UI elements from a camera ? I need to get the minimalistic display of camera as in the second screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is to use `UIImagePickerController`, which is probably the easiest way to take a photo with the camera. That class has a [`showsCameraControls`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller/1619129-showscameracontrols) property that you can set to `NO` if you don't want the usual set of controls. If you do that, though, you'll have to set the [`cameraOverlayView`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller/1619113-cameraoverlayview) property to a view that you supply. Normally, that view would contain your own set of camera controls, but you could instead pass in an empty view. You'll want to set up the view so that it responds to the user's gestures, so that they can still take the photo (with a tap, perhaps) or dismiss the camera without taking a photo (you could use a swipe for that).

Answer (score 0):

```
class Scanner: NSObject {
//MARK: - Private Properties
private var captureSession: AVCaptureSession?
private(set) var videoLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?

//MARK: - Initialization
override init() {
    super.init()

    captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    if let captureSession = captureSession {
        let device = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
        do {
            let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device)
            captureSession.addInput(input)

            let output = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
            captureSession.addOutput(output)
        } catch {
            print(error)
            abort()
        }

        videoLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: self.captureSession)
        if let videoLayer = videoLayer {
            videoLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
        }
    }
}
```

In your `UIViewController` you set it up like this:

```
let scanner = Scanner()
if let videoLayer = scanner.videoLayer {
    videoLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(videoLayer)
    scanner.startSession()
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your an answer but i got an error: Value of type 'Scanner' has no member 'startSession'

Comment: Insert `captureSession.startRunning()` after the `captureSession` is set.

Comment: I got a black screen. http://www.imageup.ru/img76/2635267/img_0313.jpg.html

Comment: Have you granted camera permissions to your app?

Comment: Try to configure the output. I didn't paste it here, because this code code is taken from a real project and the camera is used to scan QR codes, which, I assume, is not your case. Basically you should use `AVCaptureSession` and insert its layer as a sublayer of your view.